# option selected with vue-select and get value in function

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-select

I´m trying to create a select with this library, but my problem it´s that i need get info from option selected and call other function to add tr in table. I´m working with vue js 3 and composition API.

i can show, that if i use this code:

```
 <v-select :value="selected" :options="getAllItems" label="name" @change="setSelected($event)"></v-select>
>
```

i can select my option and i can show it in my select selected. but not call to my function `setSelected` and i want in this function receibe all information option selected.

My function:

```
const setSelected = (event) => {
        console.log(event.target)
    }
```

if i use `<v-select v-model="selected" :options="getAllItems" label="name" @change="setSelected($event)"></v-select>` never can show option selected in input and i can´t call to function... It´s my first time with this library.

Thanks for readme and sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

apparently in vue3, the prop **value** was renamed to **modelValue** and not updated on the docs. Had my one share of pain while dealing with this one!